# How do I perform a double assassination in Assassin's Creed III?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

This has really been bugging me throughout the game. In previous games, when you were eligible to assassinate an enemy, it would show you that you need to press the Square button in order to do so. If two enemies were standing near each other, I never seemed to have any problem assassinating both of them at the same time. All you had to do was walk up behind two enemies and it would kill both of them.

However, it seems kind of random whether or not a double assassination occurs in Assassin's Creed III. It doesn't tell you when you're eligible to perform an assassination, and I can't seem to figure out why it's not letting me do double assassinations. Following the same patterns I've always utilized in previous games yields an unexpected result - only one of the enemies is killed, and the other starts attacking me. I've only been able to pull off one double assassination in my entire time playing the game so far (out of the around twenty I've attempted) and I have no idea what I did differently that time.

How do you perform a double assassination? Am I missing some major component of the game that I'm not realizing? Am I supposed to be aligning myself in some certain way?

Comment: Are you talking about stealth double assassinations, double assassinations in open conflict or both?

Comment: Mainly stealth assassination since that's the one I try to use more often, but any details on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to perform a double assassination, you have to be in **High Profile**.  **Low Profile** kills will generally allow you to kill a single target.  It's not automatic like it was in previous games.  But it ultimately depends on the weapons used.  But in the end, it all depends on if two enemies are highlighted and not just one.

With the (Double) **Hidden Blade** equipped, when two enemies are close to each other and you are in range of both of them, you must enter high profile and assassinate them.  If you are on a higher elevation, it will almost always do a double aerial assassination.

If you are carrying a (loaded) rifle, you can kill two enemies if they are lined up one behind the other.  It doesn't matter if you stay in high or low profile for this, you'll be firing a shot and that is always a high profile move.

I don't believe there are other weapons that can kill multiple enemies in a single attack.

Comment: Note that when using the hidden blade, it doesn't seem possible to perform stealthy double assassinations anymore.  If there's more than two enemies and you try to do this, you will always be detected, even if the others are not looking.  If there are only two, you will not trigger open conflict.  I haven't been able to test this theory from a hiding spot but will try when I get the chance.

Comment: Following this, I've noticed that even jumping on small things like a rock or a fence post is considered an air assassination, which makes it a little easier to perform the double assassinations. Kind of sad walking won't do it anymore, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can stealth assassinate up to 3 people, I've tried it.

I don't know the controls for Xbox but for PS3 you press **X** to fast walk toward them and when you reach them keep on fast walking and press **Square**. After you assassinate one, press **Square** again to move to the other.

You can do this 3 times in succession

Comment: If you have to press Square again then you are just chain killing. You're not limited to three, you're just limited to the number of guards that are in the vicinity (chain killing distance) that don't notice you killing the other guards before you get to them.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured this one out, although when you do it your cover is blown. You have to have 2 people selected, to do this you must select one then you might see a feint glow on another next to him. You just equip your double blade and tap that RT/R1 + Square/X. So sprint+attack. Just tap them at the same time. Or since you are going to be detected right after anyways, just run with 2 enemies lined up and it will do a double assassination. But yeah test it on two random guards, just tap sprint and attack

Comment: So... this doesn't really differ from the accepted answer... Sprinting is entering high profile, so you're basically just sneaking up and entering high profile at the last moment, rather than entering high profile prior and running up to them.

Answer (score -2):

There is no real explanation on how to do it. I just face a guard and aim my camera at the second one and I just kill the first one and then move on to the next, and surprisingly I do not get into high profile and I don't get into any fights. I have beat the game twice now, so yeah.I know this stuff like the back of my hand.

Comment: There *is* a perfectly good explanation given in the top answer here.